# connect: cannot assign requested address

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have the following error message from a Go app in Docker:

```sh
panic: failed to connect to `host=localhost user=postgres-dev database=dev`: dial error (dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: cannot assign requested address)
```

which appear in the environment of the next `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
FROM golang:latest

WORKDIR /WD

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

COPY . .
```

the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        image: postgres:latest
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: dev
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres-dev
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: [~secret~]
            ports: 5432:5432
    app:
        build: .
        command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "go", "run", "main.go"]
        volumes:
            - .:/WD
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        depends_on: 
            - db
        links: 
            - db
```

here the `main.go` file:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    api "github.com/[placeholder]/[placeholder]/api"

    db "github.com/[placeholder]/[placeholder]/db"

    pgx "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Init")
    r := api.InitRoutes()

    conn, err := pgx.Connect(context.Background(), "postgresql://postgres-dev:[~secret~]@localhost:5432/dev")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // the error appears from this line.
    }

    dbInstance := &db.DbService{Conn: conn}

    dbInstance.Conn.Ping(context.Background())

    dbInstance.Migrate("/db/db.sql")

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)
}
```

## May this be helpful?

in console logs I found the next lines, which I think related to the problem:

```sh
db_1   | 2019-12-07 08:08:59.350 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.1 (Debian 12.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1   | 2019-12-07 08:08:59.351 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
# read the next line:
db_1   | 2019-12-07 08:08:59.351 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
```

the address of the database is `:: with port 5432` and while the program try to connect to `::1 with port 5432`, could this be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Within a container attatched to a [bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) (the default) `localhost` (127.0.0.1) is the container itself. So your `app` container is trying to access the database at port 5432 on itself (not on the host or on the `db` container). The easiest fix is to change the connection string from:

`postgresql://postgres-dev:[~secret~]@localhost:5432/dev`

to

`postgresql://postgres-dev:[~secret~]@db:5432/dev`

Note: I think you have a typo in your `docker-compose.yml` - `ports: 5432:5432` is setting an environmental variable rather than mapping a port (note that this is not actually needed for `app` to talk to `db` if they are both on the same [bridged network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) as is the case by default).

Note2: You should not need to use [links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) in this case (this is a legacy feature).