# Connecting to PostgreSql via Npgsql from ASP.NET Core 6 in a Docker Compose Stack

Tags: postgresql, docker, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm trying to create a docker-compose script to fire a stack with a PostgreSql database and an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. To test the scenario, I've created a new ASP.NET Core 6 Web API using the default template. I have then added NuGet package `Npgsql` (6.0.3), and a sample controller which just queries the DB engine version, e.g.:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public TestController(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    [HttpGet("api/dbversion")]
    public IActionResult GetVersion()
    {
        using NpgsqlConnection conn = new(_config.GetConnectionString("Default"));

        conn.Open();

        var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT version();";

        return Ok($"Version: {cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string}");
    }
}
```

I then created the Docker image for this API, and written a docker-compose script as follows:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  test-db:
    image: postgres
    # explicit container name
    # another approach using hostname: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68701716/docker-compose-postgres-connection-refused
    container_name: test-db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    networks:
      - test-network

  test-api:
    image: MYREPONAME/test-api:0.0.1
    ports:
      - 5154:80
    depends_on:
      - test-db
    environment:
      - CONNECTIONSTRINGS__DEFAULT=User ID=postgres;Password=postgres;Host=test-db;Port=5433;Database=postgres
    networks:
      - test-network

networks:
  test-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Here I'm using the official `postgres` image, setting up the default credentials, redirecting the service to port 5433 in the compose stack, and consuming it from the API within the same network. I am overwriting the connection string in the script, using as host name the container name (`test-db`); `localhost` would not be an option in a Docker network (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59224272/connect-cannot-assign-requested-address) and [here](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/225)).

When I fire this script from a Ubuntu host, I can access the DB service at port 5433, and the web API at localhost:5154/swagger/index.html. Yet, when I run the action which should connect to the database, I get a connection refused error, even though I can clearly see the DB service IP and port:

```
"Exception":"Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to 172.27.0.2:5433  
---\u003E System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused    
at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.\u003COpen\u003Eg__OpenCore|191_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.\u003CGet\u003Eg__RentAsync|28_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.\u003COpen\u003Eg__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()  
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a container connects to another container on the bridge network, you use the container port. Not the mapped port on the host. So your connection string should be

```
CONNECTIONSTRINGS__DEFAULT=User ID=postgres;Password=postgres;Host=test-db;Port=5432;Database=postgres
```

Comment: Well spotted Hans, thank you! Thinking on the host side, I had not realized I was using the wrong port...