# Unable to Get Containers to Connect Correctly

Tags: docker, go, golang-migrate

I am relatively new to Docker and I have been trying to connect my web app, psql, and the golang-migrate function. However, I have faced error after error and I have finally arrived to a point whereby I cannot figure out what's going on.

My app provides this error:

> Failed to connect to `host=/tmp user=root database=`: dial error (dial unix /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432: connect: no such file or directory)

My migrate provides this error:

> error: dial tcp: lookup postgres on 127.0.0.11:53: server misbehaving

I have been going through various forums but non seem to incorporate the migrate functionality.

Here is a copy of my **updated** docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
db:
 image: postgres:latest
 container_name: db_postgres
 environment:
   - PG_USER=postgres  
   - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
   - POSTGRES_DB=buscompanion
   - DATABASE_HOST=fullstack-postgres
 ports:
   - "5432:5432"
 healthcheck:
   test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d buscompanion -U postgres"]
   interval: 10s
   timeout: 30s
   retries: 5
 networks:
   - fullstack

app:
 container_name: full_app
 build: .
 ports: 
   - 4000:4000
 restart: on-failure
 volumes:
     - api:/usr/src/app/
 depends_on:
     - db
     - migrate      
 networks:
     - fullstack

migrate:
 image: migrate/migrate
 networks:
   - fullstack
 volumes:
   - .:/migrations/migrations
 entrypoint: migrate
 command: -path /migrations -database postgres://postgres:password@postgres:5432/buscompanion?sslmode=disable -verbose up
 depends_on:
   db:
     condition: service_healthy

volumes:
api:
networks:
 fullstack:
   driver: bridge
```

**EDIT**
Here is a how Im doing my sql.Open

**func main()**

```
addr := flag.String("port", ":4000", "HTTP network address")                                //Provides general information on where site will be located
dsn := flag.String("dsn", os.Getenv("POSTGRES_URL"), "PostgreSQL DSN (Data Source Name)") //Connects to PSQL Database. Must create shortcut and replace "COMPUTE_DB_DSN"
flag.Parse()

db, err := openDB(*dsn) //Opens Databse
if err != nil {         //Enters if the Database is not entered
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
```

**openDB() function**

```
func openDB(dsn string) (*sql.DB, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("pgx", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    //use a context to check if the DB is reachable
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Second) //specify timeout
    defer cancel()                                                          //+Defer attached to a function and executes as the last thing
    //lets ping the DB
    err = db.PingContext(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return db, nil
}
```

Comment: You app appears to be attempting to connect over a unix domain socket (probably not what you want); probably because you have not set the `COMPUTE_DB_DSN` environmental variable in your docker compose file. Your migrate is attempting to connect to `localhost` which is the [container itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59224509/11810946) (have not looked into why!). Please try to include a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question rather than linking a repo.

Comment: I have made the appropriate adjustments to the question to fit the guidelines. I previously changed the ``COMPUTE_DB_DSN`` but forgot to push the change. ``COMPUTE_DB_DSN`` was previously an environmental variable for the psql path.

Comment: The edit actually makes things worse as there is now no go code accessible :-). Hardcode the URL in your app and if that does not work then show us how you are calling `sql.Open` (e.g. `sql.Open("pgx", "postgresql://user:pass@db_postgres:5432/foobar?sslmode=disable")`. Currently you appear to be relying on shell environmental variables but you have not shown these to us (meaning any answer is a bit of a guess). I'd suggest rewriting your compose without any environmental variables (you can reintroduce these once it's working).

Comment: Sorry for all the mistakes I am quite new at this.

Comment: No worries. When I said "Hardcode the URL" I meant replace any references to `os.Getenv` etc with a raw string (as per the example I gave above).  I suspect that `dsn == ""` because you don't set any args and `POSTGRES_URL` is not mentioned in your compose file (I'm unsure where you are expecting the connection string to be come from?). The idea is to get to a **minimal** example (and help you trace the issue; often when creating such an example you will find the problem yourself). You need to help us get to the root cause (so remove all flags etc for now).